# How to get url Home.jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

When I open the page after login always `Home.jsp` not found, I do not know what's wrong with my script, this is my code, this is my code :

#### ControllerLogin :

```
public class LoginController extends HttpServlet {

    public LoginController()
    {
        sandiBank = "null";
        session = null;
        mUserDao = new MUserDao();
        sandiBIDao = new SandiBIDao();
        cabangDao = new CabangDao();
        parameterDao = new ParameterDao();
        mAccesDao = new MAccesDao();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest httpservletrequest, HttpServletResponse httpservletresponse)
        throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        httpservletrequest.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/login.jsp").forward(httpservletrequest, httpservletresponse);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String user = request.getParameter("user");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
        MUser mUser = mUserDao.getMUser(user);
        if(!mUser.isCheck())
        {
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/login.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        } else
        {
            Cabang cabang = cabangDao.getSandiBank(mUser.getKdCab());
            if(cabang.getSandiBank() != null)
                sandiBank = cabang.getSandiBank();
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/home.jsp");
            dispatcher.include(request, response);
            session = request.getSession(true);
            session.setAttribute("userid", user);
            session.setAttribute("passwd", pass);
            String userid = (String)session.getAttribute("userid");
            session.setAttribute("kdcaba", mUser.getKdCab());
            session.setAttribute("sndbnk", sandiBank);
            System.out.println(session.getAttribute("sndbnk"));
            session.setAttribute("sandikd_bank", parameterDao.getSandiBank());
            session.setMaxInactiveInterval(3600);
            request.setAttribute("sandiBI", sandiBIDao.getSandiBI());
            request.setAttribute("mAccesses", mAccesDao.getmAccesses(userid));
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private MUserDao mUserDao;
    private SandiBIDao sandiBIDao;
    private MAccesDao mAccesDao;
    private CabangDao cabangDao;
    private ParameterDao parameterDao;
    private String sandiBank;
    private HttpSession session;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/home.jsp");
```

by

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp");
```

Because login.jsp and home.jsp are in the same directory

Try this instead `<li><a href="LoginController" class="first">Home</a></li>`

Comment: Can you post your jsp?

Comment: Oke i will post in pastebin

Answer (score 0):

try

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/home.jsp");
```

"/" is interpreted as relative to the current context root.

http://www.coderanch.com/t/422371/Servlets/java/HttpServletRequest-getRequestDispatcher-behaving-strangely